# Area51 site statistics?

Tags: feature-request, area-51, statistics

We have a nice [overview of all the SE sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) where we can see how every site is doing regarding users, questions and so on.

At the bottom is the link to [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) - the staging site.

Looks like we don't have a page where we can see the site statistic of Area51. I would like to know how many users there are or how many proposals been asked and what percentage the launch rate is.....

Comment: Sorry, I see now I miss understood your question. Anyway, since it pretty I think they will release those datas after the beta test.